# Phase in Quantum Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, topological-phase, berry-pancharatnam-phase

Can somebody please give the most general answer to:

"what is a Phase of a wavefunction in quantum theory?"

I have understandings and doubts so far as follows:

1. The non-relativistic quantum mechanics being developed from Schrodinger's wave-equation, it gives out and wave-solution, which has an amplitude and a phase-factor, which modulates the aplitude over it's trajectory, and so does the Klein-Gordon Equation, as it contains the D'Alembertian.
2. The zero-point of any potential is unnecessary in classical description, since we only require the gradient of so to see any observable. Considering $V(x) \rightarrow V'(x)=V(x)+V_0$; for time-independent hamiltonian case, the eigenstate $| a'(t) \rangle \rightarrow exp(\frac{-iV_{0}(t-t_0)}{\hbar})| a(t) \rangle $, which is also the same when represented over any basis, which also shows $\langle a'(t)|a'(t) \rangle = \langle a(t)|a(t) \rangle$, but cosiderning interference of such two wavefunctions with two different zero-point potentials but same elsewise would reflect a shift in interference pattern proportional to the relative zero-point, i.e. the Scalar Aharonov Bohm Effect.
3. Also for trajectories in multiply-connected domains, the wavefunction picks up additional phase factor, and accumulation of such is non-trivial over a closed trajectory. Now this, even though keeps the single-particle physical picture unchanged from probabilistic interpretation, but interference of such wavefunctions indeed gives a physical effect of such accumulated phase factor.
   Such cases are Berry Phases, of which Aharonov-Bohm Effect (scalar and vector) is a special situation of, where the choice of Gauge of the Vector Potential over the zero-field region is picked up by the wavefunction as $\Psi \rightarrow \Psi ' = \Psi exp(\frac{iq \Lambda(\vec{x})}{\hbar c})= \Psi exp(\frac{iq}{\hbar c}\int_{path \ x} \vec{A}.d\vec{r}))$ where $\vec{A}(x)=\nabla \Lambda(\vec{x})$ which indeed gives field free scenario, i.e. $\vec{B}=0$, therefore at the interference region, enclosing a region with such vector potential gives additional phase of $exp(\frac{iq}{\hbar c}\oint A.dr)$ which is indeed an observable in the interference patter, as a shift.
4. Also path integral formulation gives the idea of the classical action over infinitesimal segments of endpoints of the trajectory as an exponential weight-factor (I am not mentioning the mathematical structure due to its length only, but one may find it in Sakurai 2nd Ed, equation 2.6.47), therefore considering an interference between between wavefunctions, it must directly have contribution from $\exp(\sum_{j}(S^+_j - S^-_j))$, where the two classical (dominant one; and retrieved in $\hbar \to 0$ limit) trajectories of the interfering matter-wave being $S^+$ and $S^-$. Now these two paths could be anything, even considering a static, and spherically symmetric mass distribution  like Schwarzchild geometry, and using the lagrangian $L=\int_{x_i}^{x_f} \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu \nu}^{SCH} \dot{x}^{\mu} \dot{x}^{\mu}$ I am expected to see an interference due to additional phase factor from both trajectories and the interference term to contain such information over the closed loop, from geometry alone. [In the drawing I have drawn the mass distribution asymmetrically w.r.t the two trajectories of interfering waves waves, because if they were symmetric w.r.t the trajectories then $\sum_{j}(S^+_j - S^-_j) \to 0 $ for Schwarzschild metric since $\partial_{\phi}$ is a killing vector, and $S^+_j=S^-_j$ for $\phi \to \phi + \pi$, which would rotate the whole picture, and each infinitesimal action would be cancelled out; BUT asymmetric position of the mass distribution with considering $r^{\pm}=r_s+\delta^{\pm}_{r}$ it can be directly shown that  $\sum_{j}(S^+_j - S^-_j) \neq 0$ and the interence term is exponentally proportional to $(\delta_{r}^+ - \delta_{r}^-)$ under suitable near-field assumptions]

Therefore this idea of Phase can be perturbed from many different cases, and all these are observables when considering interences of such wavefunctions of differently-changed-phases.

So, The explaination of what exactly is a Phase is physically very much unclear to me, though mathematically it makes sense indeed. Also any idea of topological phases (in the most general context) would be very appreciated if added.

[image]

Comment: Deep question which I am not capable of answering fully.  Would say one thing, though.  Keep in mind that *relative difference* in phases between two paths is what always produces any experimental result.  There is no experiment that can isolate any absolute phase.  So in that sense, it is the relative difference in phase, not the phase itself, that is "real".

Comment: yes, that's true, I am concerned with the notion of Phase itself at the first place!

Comment: The one part of your question that's easy to answer is that "topological phase" (as the term is most often used) has no more relation to the phase of a wavefunction / complex number than "ordered phase" or "phase transition". It's referring to a state of matter.

Comment: @ConnorBehan could you kindly describe how phase acquired by topology of a trajectories have anything to do with phase transition. I don't think that's correct idea. See 
See a paper: PATH INTEGRALS AND QUANTUM INTERFERENCE EFFECTS
IN A FIVE-DIMENSIONAL KALUZA-KLEIN THEORY  by C. Bernido Eq. 3.6, mentioned by the author, that the (m-n)(m+n+1) terms infer topological shifts!

Comment: Oh, it is absolutely possible for non-trivial topology to affect the phase (not in the statistical mechanics sense) of a wavefunction. The Berry phase is an example. It's just not what most authors mean when they say "topological phase" without any qualification.

Comment: It you don't mind, @ConnorBehan, this doesn't in anyway clear my doubt!

Comment: Right because I don't know how to. I only made the comment in case someone else who wants to try giving an epistemological meaning to "phase" has doubts about what you were asking at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much @ConnorBehan!